# select onchange update php value

Tags: php, jquery, select, onchange

I want to "connect" a select with a input text without refresh the page

This is my example

```
<select name="name_select" id="my_select">
  <option value="1">first</option>
  <option value="2">first</option>
  <option value="3">first</option>
</select>

<?php ...query(SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = value) ?>
```

Then in var $name there is value from db

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" />
```

I think I must use jquery post/get but how to update only var that I need to check db?

Comment: AJAX is meant for this

Comment: You can achieve it with ajax call because ajax will not refresh your page. Add Ajax tag in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Thamizhan say in comment, you need to use AJAX.

Here is a simple example :

**HTML** (index.html)

```
<select name="name_select" id="my_select">
  <option value="1">first</option>
  <option value="2">first</option>
  <option value="3">first</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#my_select').on('change', function () {
    var selectData = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "custom.php",
        data: {'selectData': selectData },
        success: function (json) {
            // do things
        }
    });
}
```

**PHP** (custom.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['selectData'])) {
    var_dump($_POST['selectData']); // $_POST['selectData'] is the selected value
    // query here
    // and you can return the result if you want to do some things cool ;)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#my_select").on("change", function () {
   $.ajax({
        url: "phpfile.php",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {val: $(this).val()},
        success: function (data) {
            $("[type='text']").val(data);

        }
    });
});
```

In phpfile.php

```
include("db.php");

// ... your code ...

// execute sql(SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = value) and return value.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clear one thing why you need sql query here.

```
<option value="1">first</option>
```

first is name and 1 is option there. then we can put first or 1 into input box without using sql and ajax.

use only jquery for this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my_select").change(function(){

    var thisval = $(this).val();    
    $("input").val(thisval);
  });
});
```